# Get object in controler

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I need to get the DOM object via jQuery of an element with a ng-click inside the controller.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="data in list">
        <span ng-click="editMode(this, data.id)">edit</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.editMode = function(obj, id) {
    $(obj).hide(); //do not use jQuery hide() in angular! I's just a test!
}
```

The variable **obj** has an element, but I can't work with it.
If I try **$(obj).hide();** nothing happens.

---

**Edit:** This is not the right way to hide an element in Angular! It's just used as example! Hide elements with ng-hide.

Comment: I guess the angular way would be more in lines of `ng-show="!isInEditMode"` (not sure about the precise syntax) and not external dom manipulation

Comment: Like I said in the comment below, this was just for testing. I know ng-hide and ng-show. Thanks!

Comment: Same applies for any jQuery method, not just hide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example `this` refers to the current angular `$scope` instance, not the element. The easiest way to get the element would be to pass through the event object:

```
<span ng-click="editMode($event, data.id)">edit</span>
```

Then in the handler you can access the target element:

```
$scope.editMode = function(e, id) {
    $(e.target).hide();
};
```

**Note**: this is not considered good practice with Angular. Assuming your `editMode` function does nothing but hide an element, you could achieve it with an `ng-hide` or `ng-show` directive as mentioned in the comment on your question.

Comment: Really? Your solution is to do DOM manipulation for something that can be _easily_ solved declaratively using `ng-hide`? This is _bad_ Angular. More over - this looks like it's not very testable, what I'm conceptually doing is hiding the element, not some event's target when this function executes.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - My solution is just answering the question in its current form. I agree, it's not the ideal Angular solution. I'm also assuming the function in reality does far more than just hide an element.

Comment: @JamesAllardice answers suggesting alternative pathways are _very_ acceptable. Answers teaching bad practice without saying it's bad practice, less so.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Agreed completely. An alternative pathway had already been suggested in the comments on the question, so I didn't feel the need to repeat that here. But I should probably have made a note of that in the answer.

Comment: Sorry guys. I think I posted a bad example. I know the **ng-hide** and **ng-show** way. I used this jQuery hide function just to test if the element is called. Thanks for your answer! I will try it tomorrow at work.

Answer (score 4):

Like I said in my comment, you should have a backing data model and have the reactions declared in your angular html.

Here's example fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mVCkY/

```
<li ng-repeat="data in list">
    <span ng-click="editMode(data)" ng-hide="data.isInEditMode">edit</span>
</li>

function DataCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = [{}, {}, {}];
    $scope.editMode = function(obj) {
        obj.isInEditMode = true;
    };
};
```